# how to do an integration test with angular js to REST api backend?

Tags: angularjs, rest, integration-testing

In my angularjs front end application I am calling REST services on the backend. I am a bit of a newbie in integration testing for angular. I am looking for a good guideline on how to implement this? I dont want to use httpbackend because it looks like this is mocking the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration testing generally has multiple meansings, but if your meaning is:

How do I test a user clicking something and then test that their action went all the way to the REST API and some returned result is as expected then I would take a look here:

[Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor)

Protractor has/is becoming the standard for End to End testing with Angularjs.  It provides a way to simulate user actions and get their result and make assertions.  It's built with Selenium and has a nice JavaScript wrapper so that you can keep everything in JavaScript for the front-end.  All the tests are defined then using this JavaScript wrapper and Jasmine.